# Grand canonical partition function for a degenerate two state fermion system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, fermions

Consider a two state system of fermions with energy levels $\varepsilon_1 , \varepsilon_2$ with respective degeneracies  $g_1 , g_2 $ (taking into account the spins as well) . What is the grand canonical partition function $\Xi$ ?

What I tried:

Wikipedia gives the partition function $\Xi = \prod_{q = 1,2} (1 + e^{-\beta(\varepsilon_q + \mu)})$ but this is assuming the energies to be non-degenerate (at least I think so).

So we can introduce "new" non-degenerate energy levels:

$$ \varepsilon^*_i = \varepsilon_1 \  , \    \text{for $ i = 1 ,2 , ... , g_1 $ } $$

$$ \varepsilon^*_{j+g_1} = \varepsilon_2 \  , \    \text{for $ j = 1 ,2 , ... , g_2 $ } $$

This gives $g_1 + g_2$ non- degenerate energy levels, and the partition function is:

$$ \Xi = \prod^{g_1 + g_2}_{q = 1} (1 + e^{-\beta(\varepsilon^*_q + \mu)}) = (1 + e^{-\beta(\varepsilon_1 + \mu)})^{g_1} \times (1 + e^{-\beta(\varepsilon_2 + \mu)})^{g_2}   $$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Usually, it is simpler to reason with potentials, here the grand potential by taking the logarithm. Your product of powers become a linear combination.